# Stacking labels in ArcMap without Maplex?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, labeling

I do not see any obvious setting for stacking labels in ArcMap (ArcView license).

Am I missing something or do i have to write a complex expression to stack my labels?

Comment: Can you tell us what data your field contains & how you want to stack it?

Comment: New in Version 10.1: The Maplex for ArcGIS extension functionality has been moved into the core ArcGIS for Desktop product and is referred to as the Maplex Label Engine.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This works:

```
 Function FindLabel([Name]) 
  var = [Name]
  result = ""   
  splitStr = Split(var, chr(32))
  for i = 0 to UBound(splitStr)
     tmpStr = Trim(splitStr(i))
      if len(tmpStr) > 0 then 
         if result = "" then
         result = tmpStr 
     else
        result = result & vbnewline & tmpstr    
     end if
      end if
  splitStr(i) = tmpStr
  next
  FindLabel = result
End Function
```

Answer (score 5):

You can write an expression, but its not complex.  Just type in "vbnewline" between the fields you want to label on, and it will create a stacked label.

```
[FIELD1] & vbnewline & [FIELD2]
```

Comment: Thanks. My labels are contained within 1 field so vbnewline will not work.

Comment: @Jakup- split the field value then "stack" your label using vbnewline (or vbcrlf)?

Answer (score 0):

I was getting an Error 'Invalid use of Split:Null', so I added an additional Null check before Split function, Now the new code looks like:

```
  Function FindLabel ( [Name] )
     var = [Name]
     result = ""   

   if Not IsNull(var) then
     splitStr = Split(var, chr(32))

     for i = 0 to UBound(splitStr)
       tmpStr = Trim(splitStr(i))
         if len(tmpStr) > 0 then 
           if result = "" then
              result = tmpStr 
           else
              result = result & vbnewline & tmpstr    
          end if
        end if
     splitStr(i) = tmpStr  
     next
   FindLabel = result
 End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an alternative text wrapping using python:

```
import textwrap
def FindLabel ( [Name] ):
  return textwrap.fill([Name],20)
```

Although it is probably better to use Maplex if you can.